Verifiable OPRF from general ZKP?
We know how to build a signature scheme from ZKP and hashing: For signing, the signer creates a ZK-PoK $Sig$ that it knows $k$ such that $\text{H}(k) = \text{id}$, and includes the message $m$ in the transcript (see, e.g., examples/digital-signature).
Similarly, we should be able to build a blind signature scheme: The client commits to $m$, $Com = \text{H}(r, m)$, and sends $Com$ to the signer. The signer signs $Com$ by producing a ZK-PoK $Sig$ as described above. The client then creates a blind signature by creating a ZK-PoK $BlindSig$ that certifies $\text{VerifySig}(\text{id}, Com, Sig) = 1$ and $\text{H}(r, m) = Com$.
Now, blind signatures are related to OPRFs in that a unique blind signature scheme is also an OPRF. The scheme we described above, however, doesn't yield a unique signature, as far as I can see. So, the question is: Is there a clever way to make it work?
In short: is it known how one can build a verifiable oblivious PRF using a general ZK proof system?

Do you mean like a generic compiler?

@MarcIlunga Yep.

I think you can always publish a commitment to the OPRF key. Then use a SNARK to prove knowledge of the committed key and that the protocol transcript is “consistent” with the key, input, and output. For specifc, OPRF construction lightweight ZK-proof systems will be enough to make the OPRF verifiable.

@MarcIlunga Thx for your thoughts. I meant to go one step further: Can we build a VOPRF just using a general ZKP system (without usage of additional primitives)? If not, what is the minimal primitive we need (in addition to ZKP) to build a VOPRF? Does that make sense?

Oh, I see. I don't see how that could be done, though I haven't researched all the literature. A ZK prove inherently involves a witness of some relation, which for example some arithmetic circuit. But is there any fundamental difference between "some" arithmetic circuits and a cryptographic primitive, which can also be represented by an arithmetic circuit?

Let me give some context. We know how that we can build a signature scheme from ZKP and hashing: For signing, the signer proves knowledge of k such that H(k)=id and includes the message m in the transcript (see, e.g., examples/digital-signature). I was thinking, maybe we can also build a blind signature scheme in a similar way: The client commits to m, Com = H(r, m), and sends Com to the signer. The signer signs Com as above. The signature is a ZK-PoK that VerifySig(id, Com)=1 and H(r, m)=Com. Does that make sense?

Probably best to include above in the question as additional context by copying and hitting [edit].

Have added more context to the question. @MaartenBodewes

Noice! I've formatted the question to make it easier on the eyes. Please do a quick check on the result looking at the history (icon with clock and counter rotating arrow on the left).

No, you cannot build VOPRFs from ZKP, because VOPRFs are stronger than OPRFs which imply key exchange, and ZKPs are essentially equivalent to OWFs. Basing key exchange on the existence of OWFs is arguably the most important open problem in cryptography, and is known to be impossible via blackbox reductions.
In more details:

Oblivious pseudorandom functions are equivalent to oblivious transfers.

Proof (sketch):
Let Alice have two messages $(m_0,m_1)$ and Bob have a selection bit $b$. Alice picks a PRF key $K$ and sends $m_0 + \mathsf{PRF}_K(0)$ and $m_1 + \mathsf{PRF}_K(1)$. In parallel, Alice and Bob run an OPRF protocol where Bob inputs $b$ and Alice inputs $K$. Bob obtains $\mathsf{PRF}_K(b)$ and uses it to unmask $m_b$. The OPRF security guarantees that Alice does not learn $b$ and that $\mathsf{PRF}_K(1-b)$ looks uniformly random to Bob, hence Bob learns nothing about $m_{1-b}$.
In the other direction, oblivious transfers imply generic secure computation via GMW, and OPRFs are just a particular type of two-party secure computation.

Oblivious transfer implies key exchange

It follows again from the fact that KE is a special type of 2-party computation, but it's also a classical result and an interesting exercise to show it directly.

ZKP are implied by OWFs

This is the celebrated result of GMW (not the same GMW as above).

(restating a previous sentence) Basing key exchange on the existence of OWFs is arguably the most important open problem in cryptography, and is known to be impossible via blackbox reductions.

Answering your follow-up question in the comments:

If not, what is the minimal primitive we need (in addition to ZKP) to build a VOPRF? Does that make sense?

That would be oblivious transfer, which is the core building block for virtually every MPC protocol (which OPRFs are). Note that OTs imply OWFs which imply ZKPs, so OTs alone actually suffice to build VOPRFs in a generic way.

Thanks for the elaborate answer! Can you refer to a paper that describes OT => VOPRF?

You won't find such a paper because as I said, this follows from generic template. The GMW paper I linked in my answer shows that OT => MPC, and OPRF is a form of MPC for a specific functionality. Then, adding verifiability can be done generically using ZKP. But all of that follows from folklore generic compilers, I don't think anyone wrote down this very specific concrete instantiation.
